# NSBundle sandboxing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, posix, nsbundle

Odd title, I know. What I REALLY mean to ask is something like "can I create a TrustedBSD MAC Framework or iOS sandbox for NSBundles?" I have a very dynamic application in which modules can be "plugged in" or "un plugged" to a "switchboard" at any time. The user operating it is on another computer, perhaps miles away. There's no way for users to know how the switchboard modules can be compliant and not wreck the system in their absence. I know iOS sandboxing and TrustedBSD (as well as Lion's Seatbelt.framework) can do this for processes, but how can I do this for bundle code?

Things I've thought of:

Static binary analysis of all posix calls and ObjC messaging (seems impossible as binaries are.... binary at this point, not code).

Tracing ObjC messages at runtime and logging them, locking the module out after a single stray call. (This wouldn't affect POSIX calls or any C calls for that matter, nor assembly, and would have at minimum one call already sent).

Create a sandboxed external process using XPC and load modules there, and use PDO to route switchboard calls to that process (very doable, but I need snow leopard compatibility here).

Any Ideas? I realize that a bundle, once loaded, ends up as PART of your application, so this adds further problems on implementation of security.,

Answer (score 1):

The instant that you load a bundle into your process, you are giving it full control over your process. (This is because a bundle can contain code that runs at initialization time, before you even call any of its functions.)

Tracing messages at runtime is pointless, as a malicious bundle could simply disable the code responsible for message tracing before it fires. (It's running in the same memory space, after all, and it needn't use any ObjC messages to do this.)

In short: do not load bundles you do not trust. If you must make use of an untrusted bundle, use some form of sandboxing (whether that's XPC or something else).

Comment: I completely understand this, which is why I ask, is it possible to do this? (I'm trying hard to avoid XPC or PDO here, as I've already got many, many factored PDO executables.)